# Change MouseEventArgs location

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change MouseEventArgs location property so I can use a fake location for click event, but i get this error:

"Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs.Y' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Here is my code:

```
private void ListView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     e.Location.Y = 10;
     // e.Location = new Point(x,y) doesn't work too
}
```

Comment: What does not work about creating a new instance of the `Point` structure?

Comment: You're not going to be able to set `e.Location` this way. "Read only" means exactly what it sounds like.

Comment: same error: "Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs.Location' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Comment: You can pass your own MouseEventArgs to that method if you are trying to test something.

Comment: @DangerZone i can see "read only". Am i missing some settings? Is there any other way to provide fake position?

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LarsTech suggested, I can create a new MouseEventArgs

```
private void ListView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     MouseEventArgs myEventArgs = new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, e.X, e.Y - offset, e.Delta);
     // Now I can use the new EventArgs instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[MouseEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) has 2 properties `X` and `Y` and they are both defined like this:

```
public int X { get; }

public int Y { get; }
```

See they both do not have setters, so they are read-only. That is why you cannot set them.